# WPF C# Display Image after Progress Completed

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, functional-programming

User inputs data in a textbox, selects GO from the menu. This launches a background thread and a progress bar window. When complete, the background thread creates a .png (test.txt.png) based on the textbox filename (test.txt) in the same directory. All this is working.

I'd like to display the .png file when complete. Can someone give me a little guidance on how to display the right .png file based on the file that is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying the image is as simple as adding an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to your visual tree. Loading the bitmap data from your file is also very simple: look at the second code example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S4) to create the .PNG, you could assign its filepath as a result, and access it by handling the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event.